# How can we split a pair (setOf(item), Double) into a pair (item,double) with all possible combinations?

Tags: dictionary, lambda, kotlin, set

How can we deconstruct a Pair(SetOf(item),Double)to all possible combination of Pair(Item, Double)?

Hello ! 
I am trying to learn kotlin and I am struggling with the use of the functional programming part. Especially with the lambda functions and their use on collections.

```
fun testTeam(): Set<TeamStats>{
    val team1: TeamStats=(TeamStats(team(1), setOf(player(1)),3))
    val team2: TeamStats=(TeamStats(team(1),players(1..2),5))
    val bunchOfTeams: Set<TeamStats> = setOf(team1,team2)
    return (bunchOfTeams)
}


fun main (args: Array<String>){
    val newTeam: Set<TeamStats> = testTeam()
    val decomposition = newTeam.map { Pair(it.Striker,it.Goals) }
    println("Stats: $decomposition")
}
```

I got that result:

[image: Screenshot of the current state]

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk....

Stats: [([Striker(name=Player 1)], 3), ([Striker(name=Player 1), Striker(name=Player 2)], 5)]
```

And I would like to get the following:

```
Stats: [([Striker(name=Player 1)], 3), ([Striker(name=Player 1),5) ,([Striker(name=Player 2)], 5)]
```

Maybe there are a better way to obtain that information, please free to suggest ! 
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand from your code, it should work using [`flatMap`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/flat-map.html#flatmap), e.g.:

```
newTeam.asSequence().flatMap { stats ->
  stats.Striker.asSequence().map {
    it to stats.Goals // just a convenience extension function to simplify writing Pair(it, stats.Goals)
  }
}
```

Assuming the following [`data classes`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html) and convenience functions:

```
data class TeamStats(val team : Team, val Striker: Set<Striker>, val Goals : Int?)
data class Team(val i : Int)
data class Striker(val name : String)
fun player(i : Int) = Striker("Player $i")
fun team(i : Int) = Team(i)
fun players(i : IntRange) = i.asSequence().map(::player).toSet()
```

Alternatively to the above (and with the shown `TeamStats`-class), you can also use [destructuring](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html) as follows:

```
newTeam.asSequence().flatMap { (_, strikers, goals) ->
  strikers.asSequence().map {
    it to goals
  }
}
```

which both will give the following result:

```
Stats: [(Striker(name=Player 1), 3), (Striker(name=Player 1), 5), (Striker(name=Player 2), 5)]
```

Or if you don't mind that intermediate lists are created you may also just use the above without [`asSequence()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/as-sequence.html#assequence), e.g.:

```
newTeam.flatMap { (_, strikers, goals) ->
  strikers.map {
    it to goals
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Roland !! That is exactly what I was looking for. I just don't get how in the following part of the code `strikers.asSequence() `, it knows that it deals with the element strikers and not the Set... It's a bit awkward for me.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean... `strikers` in the destructured variant is actually the `Set` `Striker`. You may want to read about [destructured declarations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html) and how they can be used in lambdas...

Answer (score 0):

You need to `map` the inner `Set<T>` using a function `F: (T) ->  Pair<T, Double>`.

**Example**

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val (set, value) = Pair(setOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 1.0)
    val result = set.map { it to value }.toSet()

    check(result == setOf(1 to 1.0, 2 to 1.0, 3 to 1.0, 4 to 1.0, 5 to 1.0))
    println(result)
}
```

**Output**

```
[(1, 1.0), (2, 1.0), (3, 1.0), (4, 1.0), (5, 1.0)]
```

Comment: thank you ! That's very instructive.
I tried your answer but I think I was not clear enough.
I actually want to start from what I already have in my current result and amend it in order to obtain my expected result.
i.e from 
[([Striker(name=Player 1)], 3), ([Striker(name=Player 1), Striker(name=Player 2)], 5)] to  [([Striker(name=Player 1)], 3), ([Striker(name=Player 1),5) ,([Striker(name=Player 2)], 5)]
if it is possible.